# How to add a "Continue" button to a top Navigation Bar in iOS/Swift

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

(Xcode6, iOS8, iPhone, Swift)

I would like to add a "Continue" button on the right of the navigation bar.

How can this be accomplished? I've been trying with some of the methods available on UIBarButtonItem, but can't get it working.

My best effort to date has been:

```
    var b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Continue", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle, target: self, action: nil)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = b
```

But I'm getting an error on the first line. It doesn't like the "style" parameter. I've also tried

```
    var b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Continue", style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain, target: self, action: nil)
```

But no luck. Still stuck on the style parameter. Any ideas? tyvm Keith :D

EDIT: For posterity, the following line also includes an `action` setting:

```
    var b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Continue", style: .Plain, target: self, action:"sayHello")
```

Reference:
[How to set the action for a UIBarButtonItem in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641350/how-to-set-the-action-for-a-uibarbuttonitem-in-swift)

Comment: `UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain`? Also, try to use `let` wherever possible (ie here)

Comment: FFFFUUUUU..... Thank you!!! And why use `let`? What difference does it make? Also, enter this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @kmiklas You should check out Apple's book on Swift. The let vs. var issue is sorted out on the first couple pages, and the answer to this question can be found in the enumerations chapter.

Comment: I downloaded into iBooks, but have been so slammed that I haven't had time to read through it.

Answer (score 10):

```
enum UIBarButtonItemStyle : Int {
case Plain
case Bordered
case Done
}
```

So you should NOT write 'UIBarButtonItemStyle', but use '.Plain' (note the dot preceding the word):

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Continue", style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)
```

To add an actual action to the button you use the following (assuming the method sayHello() exists):

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Continue", style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("sayHello"))
```

Edit: Typo in code

Comment: Ah... the `dot` is again tripping me up. In my efforts I tried `style: Plain`, which didn't work.

Comment: As a follow-up question, how is the "action" parameter properly set? I've tried `action: sayHello()` and `action: self.sayHello()` and `action:@selector(sayHello:)` with no luck

Comment: I've edited my answer to include setting an action too.

Answer (score 2):

enumerations in Swift are quite different than ObjC, in a very good way :]

Here you need to use:

```
UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain
```

You can also do:

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Continue", style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)
```

for maximum simplicity!

Side note: Use `let` instead of `var` wherever you can, its better for performance, health, etc!