# How to set the action for a UIBarButtonItem in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, action, uibarbuttonitem

How can the action for a custom UIBarButtonItem in Swift be set?

The following code successfully places the button in the navigation bar:

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Continue", style: .Plain, target: self, action:nil)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = b
```

Now, I would like to call `func sayHello() { println("Hello") }` when the button is touched. My efforts so far:

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Continue", style: .Plain, target: self, action:sayHello:)
// also with `sayHello` `sayHello()`, and `sayHello():`
```

and..

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Continue", style: .Plain, target: self, action:@selector(sayHello:))
// also with `sayHello` `sayHello()`, and `sayHello():`
```

and..

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Continue", style: .Plain, target: self, action:@selector(self.sayHello:))
// also with `self.sayHello` `self.sayHello()`, and `self.sayHello():`
```

Note that `sayHello()` appears in the intellisense, but does not work.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: For posterity, the following works:

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Continue", style: .Plain, target: self, action:"sayHello")
```

Comment: you pass selectors in swift by just putting the selector in a string, `action: "sayHello"`

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm under pressure to get this out and was getting frustrated.

Comment: This question was previously marked as a duplicate of [@selector() in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift). However, this question asks specifically about `UIBarButtonItem` while the other does not. Requiring beginners to generalize all uses of `selector` can be difficult for them, so I am removing the duplicate status so that people can keep this question up to date.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

As of Swift 2.2, there is a special syntax for compiler-time checked selectors. It uses the syntax: `#selector(methodName)`.

**Swift 3 and later:**

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem(
    title: "Continue",
    style: .plain,
    target: self,
    action: #selector(sayHello(sender:))
)

func sayHello(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
}
```

If you are unsure what the method name should look like, there is a special version of the copy command that is very helpful. Put your cursor somewhere in the base method name (e.g. sayHello) and press  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. That puts the ‘Symbol Name’ on your keyboard to be pasted. If you also hold <kbd>Command</kbd> it will copy the ‘Qualified Symbol Name’ which will include the type as well.

**Swift 2.3:**

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem(
    title: "Continue",
    style: .Plain,
    target: self,
    action: #selector(sayHello(_:))
)

func sayHello(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
}
```

This is because the first parameter name is not required in Swift 2.3 when making a method call.

You can learn more about the syntax on swift.org here: https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-2-new-features/#compile-time-checked-selectors

Comment: Just to mention that the action function cannot be **private**! I am not really sure why, but I always get an error in case I provided the name of some private function

Comment: I got this: "does not implement methodSignatureForSelector"

Comment: @AlamoPS If you're using the 2nd version with the colon, you'll need to make sure the function parameter types match that for whatever action you're handling.

Comment: I was putting Selector("sayHello"). Good to know I can just put the String

Comment: @RyanForsyth The string actually gets translated into `Selector("sayHello")` behind the scenes by Swift anyway.

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Comment: I would recommend just including the most up to date answer. People can check the edit history if they want to know what your outdated answers were. The many different answers here make it hard to sort out.

Answer (score 44):

Swift 4/5 example

```
button.target = self
button.action = #selector(buttonClicked(sender:))

@objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
}
```

Comment: This is right, for Swift 4 you need to add `@objc` to the function declaration. Up until Swift 4 this was implicitly inferred.

Comment: `button.target = self`

Comment: @Mahesh don't need to set the target

Comment: @norbDEV target is needed for Swift 5

Answer (score 6):

## Swift 5 & iOS 13+ Programmatic Example

1. You must mark your function with `@objc`, see below example!
2. No parenthesis following after the function name! Just use `#selector(name)`.
3. `private` or `public` doesn't matter; you can use private.

#### Code Example

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    let menuButtonImage = UIImage(systemName: "flame")
    let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: menuButtonImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapMenuButton))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuButton
}

@objc public func didTapMenuButton() {
    print("Hello World")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May this one help a little more

Let suppose if you want to make the bar button in a separate file(for modular approach) and want to give selector back to your viewcontroller, you can do like this :-

your Utility File

```
class GeneralUtility {

    class func customeNavigationBar(viewController: UIViewController,title:String){
        let add = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Play", style: .plain, target: viewController, action: #selector(SuperViewController.buttonClicked(sender:)));  
      viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItems = [add];
    }
}
```

Then make a SuperviewController class and define the same function on it.

```
class SuperViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    }
}
```

and In our base viewController(which inherit your SuperviewController class) override the same function

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: SuperViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        GeneralUtility.customeNavigationBar(viewController: self,title:"Event");
    }

    @objc override func buttonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
      print("button clicked")    
    } 
}
```

Now just inherit the SuperViewController in whichever class you want this barbutton.

Thanks for the read

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

if you have created `UIBarButtonItem` in Interface Builder and you connected outlet to item and want to bind selector programmatically.

Don't forget to set target and selector.

```
addAppointmentButton.action = #selector(moveToAddAppointment)
addAppointmentButton.target = self

@objc private func moveToAddAppointment() {
     self.presenter.goToCreateNewAppointment()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `target/action` using a `#selector`, you can use `primaryAction` since `iOS 14`:

```swift
// here you can set the title or a image for the UIBarButtonItem
let action = UIAction(title: "", image: UIImage(systemName: "list.dash")) { _ in
    // handler
    print("hello world")
}
        
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: nil,
                                    image: nil,
                                    primaryAction: action,
                                    menu: nil)
```